# A field reference identifier must not have the form of a qualified name

Tags: json, apache-drill

I have a json file with the following structure:

```
{
  "0.0.1":{
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "date_created":"2014-03-15"
  },
  "0.1.2":{
    "version":"0.1.2",
    "date_created":"2014-05-21"
  }
}
```

As you can see the whole json file contains just one object which is a map in which each key is the version number and the value is a new map with version and date_created properties.

I want to use Apache Drill to get a list with two columns: version and date_created

But since the keys contain dots (e.g. "0.0.1") Drill throws the following error:

```
Error: SYSTEM ERROR: UnsupportedOperationException: Unhandled field reference "0.0.1"; a field reference identifier must not have the form of a qualified name (i.e., with ".").
```

... when running a query like this:

```
SELECT KVGEN(t.*) FROM dfs.`D:/drill/sample-data/myjsonfile.json` AS t;
```

By the way, how do you tell KVGEN to process the WHOLE ROW since the row object is the actual map we want to convert?

Any ideas about how to overcome this problem?

**UPDATE:**

- Are all the map keys always different? yes they are. But I think that even in the case they were not, Drill should process them anyway and whenever it would find a duplicate, it should keep the last one (which normally is supposed to be the most recent one for most cases).
- The main problem is that the JSON file contains ONLY one big object so there is only 1 record (row) and all its properties are the actual keys to each version data. So there are NO subproperties to navigate to when using KVGEN; the idea is that KVGEN processes the WHOLE record object and not a subproperty of it.

As someone has requested to get more sample data, here it is below:

```
{
  "0.0.1":{
    "version":"0.0.1",
    "date_created":"2014-03-15"
  },
  "0.1.2":{
    "version":"0.1.2",
    "date_created":"2014-05-21"
  },
  "0.1.5":{
    "version":"0.1.5",
    "date_created":"2014-05-29"
  },
  "0.1.7":{
    "version":"0.1.7",
    "date_created":"2014-06-13"
  },
  "1.0.0":{
    "version":"1.0.0",
    "date_created":"2014-07-05"
  },
  "1.1.0":{
    "version":"1.1.0",
    "date_created":"2014-09-02"
  }
}
```

Comment: Sure. Don't use software that has "Apache" in its name, because Apache is an official home of unsalvageable projects.

Comment: when I tried the same query with above-mentioned data, I got a different error: **Error: SYSTEM ERROR: UnsupportedOperationException: Unable to get holder type for minor type [LATE] and mode [OPTIONAL]**

Comment: Is your inner map's key is always different? Please add 1-2 more records to your sample json data to get to know more about your json model.